# Remove all rows but show that is clicked specifying by id

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to show result when a user clicked a row then I will take this id and fetch related data and show it below.

```
Student Id  Total Marks     Position    View
41           525               1       Marks Sheet
42           504               2       Marks Sheet
43           504               2       Marks Sheet
44           504               2       Marks Sheet
45           504               2       Marks Sheet
```

Suppose a user clicked row 41 then the result will show below 41, after then when the user clicked 42 then the result will be show below 42 and the previous result that are in below 41 that will be hide/remove.

I have tried several times but I am unable to display,My code display only first.Like as

```
Student Id  Total Marks     Position    View
41           525               1       Marks Sheet
Your marks sheet of student id:41
42           504               2       Marks Sheet
43           504               2       Marks Sheet
44           504               2       Marks Sheet
45           504               2       Marks Sheet
```

When a user clicked on row 44 then

```
Student Id  Total Marks     Position    View
41           525               1       Marks Sheet
42           504               2       Marks Sheet
43           504               2       Marks Sheet
44           504               2       Marks Sheet
Your marks sheet of student id:44
45           504               2       Marks Sheet
```

My JS CODE:

```
 $(function(){
    $('.student').click(function(){
  var sid = this.id;
  $('.marks').not('#'+sid).remove();
  $('.marks').html("Your marks sheet of student id:"+sid);//Next,I will add user clicked studnt marks sheet from database.
    });
   });
```

php and html code:

```
echo '<tbody>';
    foreach($results as $user){
        echo '<tr><td>'. $user->stdId.'</td><td>'.$user->total_Marks.'</td><td>'.$user->position.'</td><td  class="student" id='.$user->stdId.'>Marks Sheet</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr class="marks" id='.$user->stdId.'></tr>';
   }
echo '<tr><tr></tbody>';
```

Comment: pl provide jsfiddle link

Comment: This is invalid HTML markup, IDs must be unique on document context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting id of `div` with `class="student"` (which returns all div with class="student"), but it should be current element's id which has been clicked.
   
Also you are using same id for both student and mark element, so need to change mark element id like marks_{studentId} ( see below);

```
'<tr class="marks" id="marks_'.$user->stdId.'"></tr>';
```

and use below code

```
 $(function(){
      $('.student').click(function(){
         var sid = this.id;
                   ^------^// changed this
         $('.marks').html('');// remove all mark messages
         $('#marks_'+sid ).html("<td colspan='4'>Yes that is ok."+sid+"</td>");
       });
  });
```

And if you don't wish to change mark element id then use below code, but here mark row must be next row to the student row

```
$(function(){
      $('.student').click(function(){
          var sid = $(this).attr('id');

         $('.marks').html('')// remove all mark messages

         $(this).parent().next().html("<td colspan='4'>Yes that is ok."+sid+"</td>");

       });
  });
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/48/)

Comment: You code is displayed and show only one of rows.
I need every rows the user will clicked and the message will hide from previous rows and the message will show below the current row. There may be several number of rows.

Comment: It is displaying error in $(this).parent().next().html("<td colspan="4">Yes that is ok."+sid+"</td>");

For this reason I wrote it as:
$(this).parent().next().html("<td colspan=4>Yes that is ok."+sid+"</td>");

But It is not working.

Comment: @ Bhushan Kawadkar, Is it possible to add this message with tr not td.
Because, I will add several tr and td with it instead of this message like as:
     Subject Code  Subject Tile Makrs
       E1             English     88
       H1             History      56

It will comes from jquery post. After then thes will add to my marks rows instead of message.

Answer (score 1):

here is new code. use "this" keyword to get data (id)

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
  var sid = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.marks').not('#'+sid).remove();
  $('.marks').html("Yes that is ok."+sid);
    });
   });
```

Comment: +1 even could be just: `var sid = this.id;` and could be: `$('.marks').not(this).remove();` But that means that clicked element has both classes `student` & `marks` because IDs must be unique on document context. ***EDIT:*** indeed OP's HTML markup is invalid, using duplicated IDs

Comment: You code is displayed and show only one of rows.
I need every rows the user will clicked and the message will hide from previous rows and the message will show below the current row. There may be several number of rows.